# Rails and Azure VM: where to set environment variables (mailer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, environment-variables, azure-virtual-machine, mailer

I have a Rails app hosted on an Azure virtual machine.

Every mailer tutorial recommends to store your domain and settings for incoming and outgoing emails in environment variables.

Is it safe then just to set them as normal linux env variables in the virtual machine? Or better use the Azure portal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Azure VM's you cannot set those (Env Variables) using the portal. Just ssh into the VM and set those.